# Wie wird „Titurel“ ausgesprochen?

Tags: pronunciation

Wie wird der Name [„Titurel“](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titurel) ausgesprochen? Ich kann keine Transkription oder Einspielung finden.

Comment: "Titurel"?  Achso, Wolfram von Eschenbach.  Der war vor meiner Zeit ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Der Name *Titurel* wird auf der letzten Silbe betont.

In [diesem Bayreuth-Podcast](http://www.podcast.de/episode/1683509/Titurel) sagt der Regisseur einer Aufführung das Wort (ab 1 Minute nach Start). Es klingt so: *Tie-tu-rell* (am Schluss wie im Wort "schnell"). [IPA](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationales_Phonetisches_Alphabet): /tiːtuʀɛl/

[Auf YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=titurel%20der%20fromme%20held) gibt es einige Szenen aus der Oper Parsifal, in denen der Name gesungen wird. IPA: /tɪtuʀeːl/

Comment: Es ist schwierig, Aussprache aus einer Oper zu lernen, weil sie oft jede Silbe betonen (finde ich). Ist der letzte Vokal lang oder kurz? Könntest du ein anderes Wort geben, in dem man den gleichen Laut finden kann?

Comment: D.h: Wird das letzte 'e' als 'ä' in "Fähigkeit" oder als 'e' in "Bett" ausgesprochen?

Comment: EDIT - ohne Gewähr: mit *e* wie in *schnell*.

Comment: Der Vokal in "Fähigkeit" und "Bett" klingt für mich gleich.

Comment: @teylyn: Sie sind wahrscheinlich gleich, aber der in "Fähigkeit" ist lang, während der in "Bett" kurz ist.